# Typescript use value from localstorage like key

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to  get language from localHost and use it in translation pipe like this:

```
transform(value: string): string {...
```

```
localStorage.setItem("language", JSON.stringify("en"));
```

```
let language = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("language") ?? "en");
```

```
language = language as keyof typeof translates[number];
```

```
const translates: {
      key: string;
      cz: string;
      en: string;
    }[]
```

```
let returnTranslate = "";

    translates.forEach((item) => {
      if (item["key"] === value) {
        returnTranslate = item[language];
      }
    });
```

But I get this error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ key: string; cz: string; en: string; }'

In this part of code:

```
item[language]
```

Comment: What is `value`? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Value is a string like a "dog". I updated the question with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TS compiler is not happy because you are trying to index with a type that is implicitly `any`.

But why is your `language` variable implicitly `any`? It comes from the first assignment

```
let language = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("language") ?? "en");
// language is of type any here
```

using `as` here

```
language = language as keyof typeof translates[number];
```

temporarily lets the TS compiler know that you are forcing the type here, but then you use your `language` variable (which is of type `any`) as an index later in the code and the TS compiler does not like that.

So instead, you would have to use `as` where you actually use `language` as the index

```
returnTranslate = item[language as keyof typeof translates[number]];
```

But because that is verbose and you know that your `language` should be a `keyof typeof translates[number]` all the time, you can just do it right at the beginning.

```
let language = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("language") ?? "en") as keyof typeof translates[number];
```

With this change you also get rid of the line `language = language as keyof typeof translates[number];`.

[Run this example on the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYewxghsDKAuICcIHMCmA6Azq2BJWqAtgBQBEwEAdsgK4qqkA0ABAFLQDyAclrAgJbV+AMwCeZVJVIBKaQG4AUGBCVMIYBlDJifKpgoEyAC1TBQM6QoWhIMeEjRYc+ImQrU6aJm049MfQWQRcVIwAC8LRWVVdU0QbV1VA1RjU3NZK2EaSjBYfhVmRP0IQwA3KBpUAC5mfwFqaWYAbwVmZg1YdqpaemYAXh9udAAHCARsYhsoOER6dDQ8AhJybs8GRoB+DeZSSRlmCExmAGtUURBhQtFh1AvCpCSS1EwAbUoaQgAjVAQAXUVWsxov57npkpgai02tDoadRDU6oFFDCYeEEQFqMiUW1JOj6sgsTCAL4vX6AtoDF7k6FNE5nGoAcncPTQAFpKBBCKgGSxccwGQBRajAfiYIw8oFhRkAYTCqDA4qJjGpbVpcMZJjMIAlfIZAAk0iAAIQStH8gCCRhAACsTUrqf8rG0OswEDgaAhKAAVB7FAj9HakAFtIrg9DCRACiAK4jEfhLRp9AB8zWpImYcaWL1IcNIv36fQG5WAlUaUJRbtgHu9vuSAfjRBezLWjuJgKJ8idrvdnu7Vc9PrBTwURKAA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but mainly for the explanation.